# How to add Product description after product name in catalog list?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, catalog

I am working with magento 1.7.0.2. I want to add product description after product name in the catalog list. what i will add to template/catalog/product/list.phtml ?

Tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$_product->getShortDescription()` for short description, or `$_product->getDescription()` for full description of a product.

Just place it after `$_product->getName()` is called in the file.

```
<h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
<!-- add short desc -->
<span><?php echo $_product->getShortDescription();?></span>
```